# Menu Item height size little Android

Tags: android, image, android-layout

> ```
>      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>       <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
> <item
>     android:id="@+id/menu_zain"
>     android:showAsAction="always"
>     android:icon="@drawable/logo_header_menu" />
>        </menu>
> ```

Okey I have this. On mdpi my image size ( logo header menu ) is 63 - 27...and it shows up nicely in action bar.

on hdpi  i tried 140- 60 and 94 - 40 ...unfortunately it shows up so ugly..and image diminishes in height size + width size. why does it diminish so bad and show up so ugly on hdpi?

the hdpi i tried is kit kat nexus 4..

Answer (score 0):

The Nexus 4 isn't an hdpi device. It is an xhdpi device. Thus your hdpi asset is getting scaled up for the Nexus 4.

Try providing your logo at 126x54 in the xhdpi folder.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what to tell you. "It looks ugly" isn't a good description of a problem, so it is difficult to know what the issue is.

Comment: well, if i give it say 70 - 70 pixel it works fine..width/height take 70. but if i give it 140 - 70 ...then suddenly both height and width diminish to 10 - 10 sthg.... what i gathered u cant put an image which is not square in menu. its not workint correctly with recntangular images